# Как прекратить выполнение хранимой процедуры ORACLE, используя OCCI?

Tags: c++, oracle

Как прекратить выполнение хранимой процедуры ORACLE, используя OCCI?

В OCI для таких целей есть вроде как OCIBreak. Что использовать в OCCI?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл `cancel();` вроде как заменяет сразу `OCIBreak` и `OCIReset`...

Проверил - работает!